# Join multiple rows having a common column Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I'm working on Covid data from [Our World in Data](https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/tree/master/public/data). The data is very well-documented from the start. It is adding record for every progress(for every vaccination/deaths etc). It has 67 columns and more than 161K records. 
For every record that is being added, `life_expectancy` is calculated. I wanted to calculate the average `life_expectancy` per location till date. For eg: Mexico has around 750 entries and has `life_expectancy` for every record. I want to take average for all the 750 `life_expectancy`. For this, I planned to pick up entry of each country and then calculate the average of `life_expectancy` and then add it to new dictionary. My way got me incorrect data  and also took more than 1 min to complete.

covid.head():
[image]

Here's what I tried:

```
import time
t = time.process_time()

avg_life_exp = {}
for i in covid['location']:
    count = 0
    avg = 0
    loc = i
    if i == loc:
        avg += covid['life_expectancy']
        count += 1
    else:
        avg = avg/count
    avg_life_exp[i] = avg

print(avg_life_exp)

elapsed_time = time.process_time() - t
print(elapsed_time)
```

Output (I got repeated values of the added screenshot):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and compute `mean` on `life_expectancy,`:

```
out = df.groupby('location')['life_expectancy'].mean().reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
              location  life_expectancy
0          Afghanistan            64.83
1               Africa              NaN
2              Albania            78.57
3              Algeria            76.88
4              Andorra            83.73
..                 ...              ...
233  Wallis and Futuna            79.94
234              World            72.58
235              Yemen            66.12
236             Zambia            63.89
237           Zimbabwe            61.49

[238 rows x 2 columns]
```